# Automatically close saved file tabs when opening a new file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Each time I open a file in SublimeText it shows the file in a new tab in the window. This leads to dozens of being tabs open in the current window over the course of my working day. This is ok, until I commit my changes and switch branches. At this point I am asked to verify the reloading of each files that I have previously worked on.

I rarely use the window's open file tabs to swith to editing an already "open in tab" file. I find that using Ctrl-P to switch/open files is much quicker and more convenient. Also, for the majority of the files that I want to open, sublime is so quick in loading the file fresh. Because of this, having tabs showing the recently opened files not very useful. The only time it is useful to have the tab open is to highlight files with unsaved changes.

I would like tabs without unsaved changes to automatically close as I open/navigate to another file in the window. Is there a setting/plugin that does this?

[edit] - tweaked wording in an effort for clarity

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what it is you're asking here. What do you mean by "as I move to another file"? Are you working with one window that has a lot of tabs in it or one tab per window?

Comment: @OdatNurd One window with lots of tabs. "move to another file" == "open another file by doing Ctrl-P, typing part of the file name and selecting it".

Comment: Ahh gotcha; there's no setting for this directly. A plugin can detect when files are opening and then close all other files, but this doesn't play nicely with using `Goto Anything` to select the file because browsing also triggers load events. So as you're deciding what to open next everything else would close. Is that an issue?

Comment: Ah, TIL "Goto Anything" is the Ctrl-P method of opening files. I would be happy for all other files to close, as long the files with unsaved changes remain open. GotoAnything appears to work like double clicking a file in the tree (single click shows the file, double click opens it in a new tab). I'd also be happy if I could modify GotoAnything to just not permanently open a tab for a file until I have edited the file.

Comment: That's not currently possible; although there is a setting that controls this for the sidebar (`preview_on_click`), it doesn't have any effect on the `Goto Anything` panel. To do that a plugin would be needed that recreates what that does, but that would lose you the speed because the current one is in the core.

Comment: As an FYI I have a sample plugin that will do this, but it has the unintended side effect of blocking you from viewing your preferences. I'll need to poke that a little more to see if I can make it a bit more intelligent.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks so much for your efforts, and apologies for not thanking your earlier - it seems my last comment thanking you didn't submit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? 
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/close-tab-after-delete-file/9439/6

Close buffers on file delete

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Whilst that sounds useful, it's not really what I am after as I am more concerned with drowning in tabs after a session on a codebase.